# Error when dynamically creating XML

Tags: php, xml

I want to create an `XML` document of this type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<libreria version="1">
<libri>

</libri>
</libreria>
```

and then insert in various other fields like `<libro><data></data></libro>`.

I created the following code:

```
<?php
$note=<<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<libreria version="1">
</libreria>
XML;
$mioArray = new SimpleXMLElement($note); 
$result =$mioArray->addChild('libri');
$result2 = $result->addChild('libro');
$result2->addChild('data', 22);
echo $result2->asXML();
?>
```

But when print the output, I don't see the first part in this `$notes` .
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `$notes`? What is `first part`?

Comment: excuse me $note the xml code inside $note is the first part of xml document "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<libreria version="1">
</libreria> ".

Comment: Change `echo $result2->asXML();` to `echo $mioArray->asXML();` and check

Comment: @DanDi please check the comment and answer as well. If it works for you then mark and up-vote the answer for others help.

Comment: I am deleting my answer because it seems that it not helps you.

Comment: excuse me, your code work very well!